# Picking a different column in each row of a Dataset[]

Tags: filtering, dataset

I have a `Dataset[]` like this:

```
ds = Dataset[{
   <|"x" -> 1, "a" -> Missing[], "b" -> 10, "c" -> 14|>,
   <|"x" -> 1, "a" -> Missing[], "b" -> Missing[], 
    "c" -> Missing[]|>,
   <|"x" -> 2, "a" -> 12, "b" -> 13, "c" -> 16|>,
   <|"x" -> 1, "a" -> 11, "b" -> Missing[], "c" -> 15|>
   }]
```

The keys `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"` are hierarchical, and I would like to get the first non-`Missing` key/value pair for a given value of `"x"`.

For instance, for each `"x" -> 1`, I'd like to get the first key/value pair for which the value is not `Missing[]`. The output would look something like this:

```
{"b" -> 10, "x" -> Missing[], "a" -> 11}
```

The key `"x"` in the second result is irrelevant as long as the value is `Missing[]`.

I can extract the desired keys, more or less:

```
ClearAll[firstoption];
firstoption[x_] := First[Position[x[[{"a", "b", "c"}]],
     _?(! MissingQ[#] &), 1, Heads -> False] /. {} -> {{Missing[]}}];

ds[Select[#x == 1 &], firstoption] // Normal
(*  {{Key["b"]}, {Missing[]}, {Key["a"]}}  *)
```

The next step would be to `MapThread` `Lookup` on the `{rows, keys}`:

```
MapThread[
 (#2 /. Missing[] -> "x") -> Lookup[##, Missing[]] &,
 {Normal@ds[Select[#x == 1 &]],
  Flatten@Normal@ds[Select[#x == 1 &], firstoption]}]
(*  {Key["b"] -> 10, "x" -> Missing[], Key["a"] -> 11}  *)
```

OK, so that's pretty much what I wanted. The head `Key` doesn't matter. I can remove it (or add it) easily.

My question is, *Is this the best way to do this?*

I have my doubts.  My approach seems tortuous.  `MapThread` does not work with `Dataset[]`, so either it's an oversight or there's a better way to do this.

Comment: In your first example, should it have be {"b"->10,"c"->Missing[],"a"->11}?    You appear to be using "x"->1 to decide what values of the keys {"a","b","c"} so I would expect "c", not "x" to be in the first reported result.  Just making sure I understand.

Comment: @MarkR He wants to select the first key-value that is not missing and default to `"x" -> Missing[]` when no such pair exist.  You are suggesting to select the last `Missing` when no non-missing exist. Not the same.

Comment: @MarkR Edmund is right. I'd prefer the key for `Missing[]` to not be one of `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"c"`, because I'd like the presence of the key to indicate that option was chosen first; however, if the coding were somehow natural for the key to be `"c"` or some other string, that would be acceptable if the value were still `Missing[]`, indicating that none of the options were chosen.

Comment: @Edmund, thanks for the clarification.  I misunderstood and was trying to "aggregate" the result rather than give results for individual rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `Dataset`'s syntax sugar you may implicitly use `Query`.

`ds` as in OP, then

```
ds[
 GroupBy["x"],
 All,
 KeyDrop["x"] /*
  Normal /*
  Curry[SelectFirst, {3, 1, 2}][FreeQ[_Missing], "x" -> Missing[]]
 ] //Normal
```

> ```
> <|1 -> {"b" -> 10, "x" -> Missing[], "a" -> 11}, 2 -> {"a" -> 12}|>
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I like getting an `Association` for the whole dataset all at once, too. In my actual use-case there are many columns interspersed, but it seems I can use `KeyTake[{"a", "b", "c"}]` instead of `KeyDrop[]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  If you only want to evaluate for a particular value of `"x"` then just swap out the `GroupBy` for a `Select` and drop the `All` level. Good that swapping `KeyDrop` for `KeyTake` works out.

Comment: Thanks again. This morning I had an insight and think I'm beginning to grok descending vs. ascending and `/*`. Before when I made a mistake with `Dataset`, I'd just go back to ordinary arrays. I'm hoping eventually `Dataset` will seem easier, more natural, and more powerful.

Answer (score 5):

```
foo = Select[MatchQ[Except[_Missing]]] /* 
      (# /.  Association[] -> Association["x" ->  Missing[]] &) /* 
      KeyValueMap[Rule] /* 
      First;

ds2 = ds[Select[#x == 1 &], {"a", "b", "c"} /* <|"fc" -> foo|>];

Join[ds[Select[#x == 1 &]], ds2, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is nice, too! Hard to choose....